# I need to convert a yearly data into a quarterly and monthly data?

Tags: data-transformation

Can anybody please help me convert yearly data into monthly and quarterly data?

Comment: Calm down, and go collect some quarterly and monthly data. Higher level of temporal scale cannot be decomposed into lower level, unless you are willing to make some assumptions which are often unrealistic.

Comment: Why downvote and ask to close this? User41793 is asking a question others might ask. The answer (see my post or the comment by @Penguin_Knight) may be obvious to us, but it is not obvious to everyone.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterFlom, I see your point and I have retracted mine.

Comment: Welcome to our site! This question needs more detail to be answerable. You can edit it to do so. Please consult our [help] for suggestions.

Comment: What is the purpose? I've seen people doing this to prop up the statistics by increasing the sample size this way. I hope it's not what you're trying to do here

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the site.

Unless you are willing to make assumptions, there is no way to convert yearly data into monthly or quarterly data.

If you are willing to make the assumption that whatever it is you have data on happens at a uniform rate throughout the year then quarterly data would just be yearly data divided by 4.  Monthly data is a little trickier, but not much. You'd need to multiply the yearly data by (days in month)/365 to get close. If you want to account for leap years too, you can.

But that assumption is awfully dangerous; few things happen at the same rate all year.  There may be other assumptions that are more reasonable.

Comment: Yes, assumptions are needed--but you appear to have made some additional unstated assumptions that could confuse the unwary. One of them is that these data are cumulative totals. What, for example, would happen with annual mean temperatures?  Would you propose dividing them all by four?  Even in an area where temperatures never vary (a "uniform rate")? :-)

Answer (score 5):

We need to make assumptions to convert a time series from quarterly to monthly. Sometimes, one must transform a series from quarterly to monthly since one must have the same frequency across all variables to run a regression. In Economics,  it is common to use the  cubic spline interpolation to convert quarterly data into monthly. Let's assume that we have n quarterly data points, which implies n - 1 spaces between them. Across each space, we draw a unique 3rd-degree polynomial connecting two points. If you are conducting your analysis in excel, you can do this: http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/cubic-splines/

There is a package in R that performs the cubic spline interpolation.
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/splinefun.html

If you plan to use the data with cubic splines in a regression, be careful with autocorrelation in the residuals. In this case, it is recommend to use the Newey-West standard errors as they are robust against the autocorrelation caused by the cubic splines.